# Why does the tornado logger come with a StreamHandler attached?

Tags: python, logging, spyder, tornado

I just discovered this very strange behaviour of the logging module in Spyder:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger("hurricane").handlers
Out[2]: []  # expected

logging.getLogger("tornado").handlers
Out[3]: [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]  # Where does that StreamHandler come from?!
```

Note that these are the first lines from a freshly started interpreter. So I haven't imported `tornado` or any other package except `logging`. Yet, unlike any other logger I tried to get, it comes with a `StreamHandler` attached.

**Why?**

Related question: [How to prevent Python Tornado from logging to stdout/console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540225/how-to-prevent-python-tornado-from-logging-to-stdout-console/69118832#69118832)

Comment: It appears starting from Python 3.2, `StreamHandler` is attached by default: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided. The docs also mention to set `logging.lastResort = None` to get pre 3.2 behaviour.

Comment: @xyres that's not relevant to my question. `StreamHandler` is not attached to every logger, it just acts as a handler of last resort. What's puzzling me is that specifically a supposedly new logger (since I haven't defined any loggers or imported any libraries) has a `StreamHandler` attached if I name it `"tornado"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tornado uses `logging` for its normal-operation request logging. This is not a great idea - an application is supposed to work exactly as before if all logging is disabled (aside from the logging part, of course) but numerous web server authors use `logging` functionality as a convenience to do part of their normal operation rather than just using it for diagnostics. I believe you can turn this off using a `logging=none` configuration option; see [this page](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/log.html?highlight=logging) for more information.

Comment: And Spyder uses Tornado? For what?